# How make this type list of abbreviations

Tags: align, longtable, nomenclature, makeindex, nomencl

I want to make list of abbreviations like this picture

[image: nomenclature]

From the picture, there are two groups: "Singkatan" and "Lambang"

For each group, the header's align  are (left, center, left)
while the body's align are (left, left, center)

I try to make it using nomencl package, but ended up with (left,left,right) for both header's and body's

Is there any way to make list of abbreviations that similar to the picture using either using nomencl or nomentbl? Or with any other package?

Thank you for your kind help

Note: the number in the right of the body is the page of the symbol first appearance

Comment: Have you checked the [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package? I'm currently doing something similar to this, I could post an answer if that package is an option for you.

Comment: I have not check glossaries yet, but I think glossaries is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Using no packages at all, you could just make a table.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand\SINGKATAN[3]{#1&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{#2}}&#3\\}
\newcommand\LAMBANG[3]{$#1$&\multicolumn{1}{l}{#2}&#3\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\Large \textbf{DAFTAR SINGKATAN DAN LAMBANG}}}\\~\\
SINGKATAN&Nama&Pemakaian\\
&&pertama kali\\
&&pada halaman\\
\SINGKATAN{HPLC}{High Performance Liquid Chromatography}{10}
\SINGKATAN{NMR}{Nuclear Magnetic Resonance}{1}
\SINGKATAN{PCR}{Polymerase Chain Reaction}{13}
&&\\
LAMBANG&&\\
\LAMBANG{A}{Konstanta pada hubungan tegangan}{17}
\LAMBANG{a_1}{Kecepatan}{20}
\LAMBANG{a_{ij}}{Fungisi reaksi variabel dalam koefisien}{24}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{persamaan diferensial}&\\
\LAMBANG{b}{Parsamaan dasar perambatan gelombang}{15}
\LAMBANG{c_0}{Gaya badan spesifik}{31}
\LAMBANG{a_1}{Variabel internal pertama}{32}
\LAMBANG{a_2}{Variabel internal kedua}{28}
\LAMBANG{\delta}{Koefisien viskositas}{34}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your kind help. Table or long table would be my last option to make this. I consider, there is a lot of input data for the body. I think It would be take some time to input manually all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then Let's go for a way using the [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package.

The glossary package already does support a hierarchical structured index. However, not every style does, and none matches yor wishes. So you will have to write your own.
This is an example style. It does not match exactly what you want, but it comes close. Most of it is quite straightforward, so I guess you can modify it:

```
% define a glossary style
\newglossarystyle{tablehierarc}{%
    % base this style on the list style
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}%
    % Change the table type --> 3 columns and make sure the table definitions match
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\columnwidth}c}%
        \toprule
    }{
        \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
    }%
    % clear any weird headings, we do not want those
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    % Change the table header
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        & \textbf{Nama} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{Pemakaian pertama kali pada halaman} \tabularnewline
        \midrule %
        \endhead %
    }%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        % Here I somehow fail to position it nicely. However, a new row
        % with some negative spacing appears to work just fine.
        \\[-1ex]
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\hspace{\glosshierarchindent}\textbf{{\glossentryname{##1}}}} \tabularnewline
    }
    % Change the displayed items
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{
        \ifglshassymbol{##2}{ % Entry Symbol
                \glstarget{##2}{\glossentrysymbol{##2}}%
            }{ % or if no symbol, use name 
                \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}%
            }%
            & \glossentrydesc{##2}              % Description
            & ##3                       % Pagenumber
            \tabularnewline
    }
}
```

Next thing you will have to do is to add all entries in your glossary. Since you want a hierarchical structure, you will have to add the main elements first, and then the subitems defining the `parent` option. I'd suggest you to simply define a new command. An example for this would be:

```
\newglossaryentry{SINGKATAN}{name={SINGKATAN}, description={\glspar}}
\newcommand{\newSINGKATANentry}[3]{
    % create the glossary entry in the greek category
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#1,
        symbol=#2,
        description=\textit{#3},
        parent=SINGKATAN
    }
}

\newSINGKATANentry{hlpc}{HPLC}{High Performance Liquid Chromatography}
\newSINGKATANentry{nmr}{NMR}{Nulcear Magnetic Resonance}

\newglossaryentry{LAMBANG}{name={LAMBANG}, description={\glspar}}
\newcommand{\newLAMBANGentry}[3]{
    % create the glossary entry in the greek category
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#1,
        symbol=\ensuremath{#2},
        description={#3},
        parent=LAMBANG
    }
}

\newLAMBANGentry{a}{A}{Konstanta pada hubungan tegangan}
\newLAMBANGentry{a1}{a_1}{Kecepatan}
```

This takes care of using the correct parent, invoking math mode, putting the description in italics etc.
At this point, all you need to do is print your glossary. So, to have a complete, working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

% define a glossary style
\newglossarystyle{tablehierarc}{%
    % some configuration options
    \newlength{\glosshierarchindent}\setlength{\glosshierarchindent}{1cm}
    % base this style on the list style
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}%
    %
    % Change the table type --> 3 columns
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\columnwidth}c}%
        \toprule
    }{
        \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
    }%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    % Change the table header
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        & \textbf{Nama} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{Pemakaian pertama kali pada halaman} \tabularnewline
        \midrule %
        \endhead %
    }%
    %
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        % would prefer multicolumn environment for a more precise positioning, but
        %   this does not work (misplace \omit)
        %& \hspace{-\glosshierarchindent} \textbf{{\glossentryname{##1}}} & \tabularnewline
        % or we add additional space with a new line, which again is reduced
        \\[-1ex]
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\hspace{\glosshierarchindent}\textbf{{\glossentryname{##1}}}} \tabularnewline
    }
    % Change the displayed items
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{
        \ifglshassymbol{##2}{ % Entry Symbol
                \glstarget{##2}{\glossentrysymbol{##2}}%
            }{ % or if no symbol, use name 
                \glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}%
            }%
            & \glossentrydesc{##2}              % Description
            & ##3                       % Pagenumber
            \tabularnewline
    }
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{SINGKATAN}{name={SINGKATAN}, description={\glspar}}
\newcommand{\newSINGKATANentry}[3]{
    % create the glossary entry in the greek category
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#1,
        symbol=#2,
        description=\textit{#3},
        parent=SINGKATAN
    }
}

\newSINGKATANentry{hlpc}{HPLC}{High Performance Liquid Chromatography}
\newSINGKATANentry{nmr}{NMR}{Nulcear Magnetic Resonance}

\newglossaryentry{LAMBANG}{name={LAMBANG}, description={\glspar}}
\newcommand{\newLAMBANGentry}[3]{
    % create the glossary entry in the greek category
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#1,
        symbol=\ensuremath{#2},
        description={#3},
        parent=LAMBANG
    }
}

\newLAMBANGentry{a}{A}{Konstanta pada hubungan tegangan}
\newLAMBANGentry{a1}{a_1}{Kecepatan}

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=main, style=tablehierarc]

\end{document}
```

Giving the result:
[image]

As this thing is a normal table, you can do (nearly) any formatting you are used to to modify it. I admit, it's not exactly what you asked for, but it's close. 
If you have any specific problems modifying it, you are welcome to ask in the comments (I guess).